# How do you make buttons programmatically on the fly using Xamarin iOS with text from a API(JSON)?

Tags: ios, swift, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I would like to add buttons on the fly. without knowing how many for each Collection-view Cell eg it can be one button "tag" for a single cell or it could 3 for the next cell  or it can also be zero for all my cells which are 10 in total. everything depends on my Api as to how many buttons "Tags" I will have per cell. In a Nutshell -->I get tags from json---> then create buttons on the fly ---> then bind the button text with string from json api.I'm using Mvvmcross iOS [this is a demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Iqs9.jpg)

```
DEMO Json  --> {
      "tags": [],
      "custom_tags": [
        "Football",
        "Latest news",
        "News",
        "abc",
        "abc football",
        "abc Football",
        "abc Ladies Football",
        "abc Women's Football",
        "abc football",
        "123 Football",
        "111Football Ladies",
        "womens",
        "Womens Football"
      ]}
```

Mvvmcross iOS Demo -->

```
UIButton button = new UIButton();
button.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 60, 50, 30);
button.SetTitle("Title", UIControlState.Normal);
button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;

UIButton button2 = new UIButton();
button2.Frame = new RectangleF(60, 60, 50, 30);
button2.SetTitle("Title 2", UIControlState.Normal);
button2.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;


this.AddSubview(button2);
this.AddSubview(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

just loop through your list of tags and dynamically create the buttons

```
foreach (var tag in custom_tags) {
  UIButton button = new UIButton();
  button.SetTitle(tag, UIControlState.Normal);
  // do other config here
  this.AddSubview(button)
}
```

Comment: I'm still new to Mvvmcross iOS...How does this code work and where do I add it?

Comment: this is just basic C# - it loops through your tags and creates a new button for each tag.  You would put the code wherever you need to create your buttons.